# Binomial theorem for trace of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-theorem

I am curries whether the following binomial theorem is correct:
\begin{align}
\left( \text{Trace} (v-u)(v-u)^T \right)^n =\sum  { n \choose i}  \text{Trace}(vv^T)^{n-i} \text{Trace}(uu^T)^i
\end{align}
If not how to properly expand $\left( \text{Trace} (v-u)(v-u)^T \right)^n$?

I searched through my linear algebra reference but couldn't find anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}$ are in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Since the trace of an outer product is an inner product, then the L.H.S. is $$\left( \sum^m_{i=1} (v_i-u_i)^2 \right)^n= \left( \sum^m_{i=1} (v_i^2+u_i^2-2u_i v_i) \right)^n$$
The R.H.S is $$\left( \sum^m_{i=1} (v_i^2+u_i^2) \right)^n$$

The equality of the expressions are true iff $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v} $ and perpendicular, i.e. $\sum^m_{i=1} u_i v_i =0$